# Consolidate data for weeks to months and quarters, weeks are like W1, W2 and not in date format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've data like this below and want to consolidate data for months and then quarters. Problem is in one month there are 4 weeks and in another month I've 5 weeks, so I can't just apply formula and drag it especially if I've thousands of rows... Any hint would be appreciated.

Data is like this:

```
Month| Weeks| Sales    
M1| W1|50    
M1|W1|30    
M1| W1|40    
M1|W1|20    
M2| W1|50    
M2|W2|30    
M2| W3|40    
M2|W4|20    
M2|W5|20
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to post images here on stackoverflow.

Anyways; will a `PivotTable` do the job for you? Mark the data and then `Insert -> PivotTable`. You are working in Excel, right?

Comment: I've huge data, and a column called as Ending inventory. ending inventory of week w4 should be the ending inventory for Month M1 too, I hope you got my problem, thats why I cant use pivot. I cant use the pattern of dragging as some months have 5 weeks, in that case week5 data should be the ending inventory

Comment: I suggest you extend your original post with your goal - how should the result look like given your above example?